# React-Native: Getting forms to send info to server (undefined is not a function)

Tags: forms, reactjs, react-native, registration

I have been attempting to make a registration app and I'm experiencing this event handling error when I try to submit the new field values

[image]

The code for my forms can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/jqed-xuereb/3984107988ca8d8aeb6566141c749a59) and [here](https://gist.github.com/jqed-xuereb/9dbe0cf89d61617cd6dc7264fce68741). 
The code for event handling and sending the JSON object to the server can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/jqed-xuereb/7a70a276aaeed4a7b239cff6d20fd36c).

I would very much appreciate any form of way-pointing or advice.
Thanks

J

Comment: Please edit your answer and include the relevant code rather than posting links to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is quite self explanatory. You call `this.handlePress` in your `NameFields` component, but that component has no `handlePress` method.

Simply add that method to the component.

From looking at your other Gists, `handlePress` is part of the `Registration` component. Therefore, you will need to pass the `handlePress` through to the `nameFields` component so that it can use it (via props is a simple solution).